# Resize from one-node redshift cluster to two-nodes using snapshots

Tags: amazon-web-services, resize, amazon-redshift, upgrade, snapshot

I have an amazon `redshift` cluster with only one node `(dc2.large type)`. Now, I want to scale to two nodes and am considering the best way to go (by best I mean as fast as possible).

From the documentation there are about two options:

1. **Unload & Copy from S3**

   - I've tried this, but it just takes too long, since I have ~ 207021000 records. Also, I would then still need to do some loading / copying for the data tracked during the copy time
2. **Using snapshots**

   - This sounds as a good solution for this case. It's not that slow and I can do it with less overhead. The only issue is that if you try to restore a cluster from snapshot, you cannot change the number of nodes (at least not using aws management console)

Is there a way to use a snapshot, but on the same time also change the number of nodes? Or is the unload/copy to/from S3 the only way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change the number of nodes when restoring a snapshot.

If you wish to change the number of nodes, then simply tell Redshift to resize the cluster. There is no need to export the data or take a manual snapshot.

See: [Resizing Clusters in Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/rs-resize-tutorial.html)

Comment: Since I have only one node, I cannot use the elastic resize yet. Classic resize is not really an option, since it does not give an approximate estimation of how long it will take (aws says it might take from hours to even days - which downtime I cannot really tolerate)

Comment: Feel free to experiment by using a snapshot to create a new (1-node) cluster, then perform a resize. Then, you can delete it. That way, you'll know how long it will take. It is _possible_ that a resize goes quicker if there is a recent snapshot (depending on whether snapshots are incremental in nature), so keep that in mind when doing the resize of the Production database.

Comment: yes, that sounds as a good idea indeed. Will go for it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create a CNAME for your cluster endpoint(Hope you already have one). You can try creating a new cluster with latest snapshot, do a classic re-size on the new cluster.

Once re-sized, repoint the CNAME to new cluster's endpoint. By this way, you can avoid the downtime.

Maintenance window will still be there since we should not be allowing writes while re-sizing and re-pointing.